# AngularJS $timeout isn't waiting for UI-Router to finish rendering before computing values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-amd

I'm using `angularJS` and `requirejs` via `angularAMD` to wire together a complex application.

One of my states has two simple views like so:

```
  $stateProvider
    .state("common", {
      url: "/",
      views: {
        "view1": {
          templateUrl: "view1.tpl.html"
          },
        "view2": {
          templateUrl: "view2.tpl.html"
        }
      }
    });
```

html

```
<div ui-view="view1"></div>
<div ui-view="view2"></div>
```

`View1` has a directive:

```
  .directive('checkViewOneBoxWidth', function ($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        var linkFunctionAfterDomComplete = function () {
          console.log(elem[0].scrollWidth);
        }
        $timeout(linkFunctionAfterDomComplete, 0);
      }
    }
  })
```

And `view2` has a stylesheet that applies some styling to the page, including changing the `height` and `width` of the `view1` container.

I want the function `linkFunctionAfterDomComplete` to compute the element's `height` and `width` properties ***after*** the DOM has been modified by the stylesheet in `view2`, so I wrapped the `linkFunctionAfterDomComplete` function in a `$timeout()`.

The `console.log` from `checkViewOneBoxWidth` here is reporting the size of this element, before the styling from the stylesheet in `view2` modified the size of this element, despite the fact that we would expect the `$timeout` to cause the `linkFunctionAfterDomComplete` function to calculate the size of this element after styling from `view2` is applied and the DOM is complete.

How can I get `linkFunctionAfterDomComplete` to calculate element properties that reflect those which reflect the true state of the element after it had been fully rendered and all styling has been applied?

http://plnkr.co/edit/WjGogh?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a function to `$timeout`:

```
$timeout(function() {
  console.log('timeout: view 1 linked')
}, 0);
```

Or:

```
var fn = function () {
  console.log('timeout: view 1 linked');
};

$timeout(fn, 0);
```

The following:

```
$timeout(console.log('timeout: view 1 linked'), 0);
```

Will execute the `console.log` instantly then pass the return value (`undefined`) as the first argument to `$timeout`.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/zWgoJihcMH693fWfUp09?p=preview

Not sure if you have the same problem in your real application, but thought I should post this anyway.

---

### New answer based on edit

The problem is that your link element is located in the view template instead of in the index.html.

If you move it to index.html it will work as you expect (and you don't need the `$timeout` in this case, unless your real application adds custom HTML from the directive):

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/m3sriF2YYH5T8y42R5Lr?p=preview

If you keep the link in the view template and keep the timeout, this is basically what happens:

1. Angular will run its compile function to prepare all the bindings and the views.
2. The HTML from the views will be inserted into the DOM, the directives will execute and the `console.log` will be added to the timeout queue.
3. The link element has now been inserted into the DOM and the browser will start retrieving the CSS. The `console.log` in the timeout queue will execute.

Note that the fetching of the CSS is asynchronous and the `console.log` from the timeout queue will execute before the fetching and parsing of the CSS has finished.

Also note that you might see different behaviors in different browsers.

There are solutions, but it might get really messy.

To read more about it:

[When is a stylesheet really loaded?](http://www.phpied.com/when-is-a-stylesheet-really-loaded/)

I would recommend to just move the link to the index.html.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Very silly of me to overlook that ```console.log```  will be executed immediately. As you suspect, unfortunately, in my real application I'm passing a function to ```$timeout```. Now I'm going to have to go through my plnkr again with that insight and see if I can reproduce the issue I'm having locally when I pass a function to ```$timeout```. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Let me know if you update and I will take a look again.

Comment: Modified the question, take a look-- thanks a bunch :-)

Comment: Yes, updated the originally linked PLNKR here: http://plnkr.co/edit/WjGogh?p=preview

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. This sounds good. In the interests of modularizing my requests, is there any way you could point me in the right direction on how I could make sure that the directive is linked after the stylesheet is loaded? Or is such behavior mostly unsupported?

Comment: Move the link element to the index.html, or you have to listen for the load event. Problem is that directive1 would need to know that directive2 has a stylesheet link in it's template, which isn't really optimal.

Comment: Hard to give a good solution without knowing the real scenario. Here is one solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/KJ2qKv1ABeT5buukbToC?p=preview. The 'notify' directive is placed on the stylesheet link and will emit an event when it's loaded. This will work in Chrome, for cross-browser solutions you might need to add more code, as the link I posted earlier stated.